# Edit regex according to the validation link

Tags: regex, validation

I created a simple regex for the validation examples of the links below:

```
http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XODQxOTg0ODg0.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n66NLBbQ53w
```

but I got a request from the user to validate the following link:

```
http://events.youku.com/2014/misc/api/video-files.php?vid=XMjg3MzQ5NTg4
```

The regex is:

```
^http(?:s)?:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:v\.)?(?:(?:youtube)|(?:youku))\.\w{2,}\/(?:(?:watch\?(?=[^?]*v=?\-?\w+)(?:[^\s?,^\&amp;?]+)?)|(?:v_show\/id_(?:\w{10,})(?:\.html)?))$
```

But as the mapping fields are growing I couldn't control my regex and I couldn't find a solution.

Can anyone please help me? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't have one regex for each, loop through, and keep track of if it matched any? It seems like that'd be the more scalable solution.

Comment: Actually we are giving this expression to the our configuration file and it should be one regex.

Comment: Then you should update your software file to allow multiple, because as people request more and more it's gonna become impossible to make a regex to validate them all. What are you using? Please provide some more informative tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that all depends upon what part of the new URL is "fixed". If the year part is always 4 digits, and `misc/api/video-files.php` will always be present, you can use the following fix:

```
^http(?:s)?:\/\/(?:www\.|events\.)?(?:v\.)?(?:(?:youtube)|(?:youku))\.\w{2,}\/(?:(?:\d{4}\/[^\/]+\/api\/video-files\.php\?\w+=\w+|watch\?(?=[^?]*v=?\-?\w+)(?:[^\s?,^\&amp;?]+)?)|(?:v_show\/id_(?:\w{10,})(?:\.html)?))$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zC2dW5/3)

Comment: Thank you, could we fix the misc part also ? It can be any word that has no limitation for the characters.

Comment: Yes, we can replace `misc` with "everything that is not a slash, 1 or more repetions` = `[^\/]+`